# "Your connection is not private" when trying to access glassfish through https

Tags: google-chrome, https, glassfish, localhost

If I access my glassfish server at `http://localhost:8080`, I receive the glassfish welcome page, as it should be. But if I try to access the other http listener at `https://localhost:8181`, I receive a message like that:

[image]
(illustrative image)

How can I avoid this error message (thinking that I don't want my clients to see it)?

Answer (score 0):

This is because GlassFish generates self-signed certificates for authentication (s1as and glassfish-instance). Your browser is (rightly) complaining that it doesn't trust these certificates, because anyone can fake them for a "man-in-the-middle" attack.

To get around this, you will need to obtain a new private key and certificate from a trusted CA to replace the self-signed ones.

These can then be imported to your `keystore,jks` and `cacerts.jks`, or you can create new keystores. If you're unfamiliar with how this works, I would suggest making backups of the originals, then importing to the existing keystores, since the communication between DAS and instances relies on certificates for authentication in a lot of places.

The [GlassFish 4 Security Guide [PDF]](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/security-guide.pdf) should help you.